# Attribute Error While Processing the Python (wxpython) Code

Tags: python, import, wxpython, attributeerror

Hey I Am Getting the error while processing this python code . Please Note that i am new to python . Thanks

Here is the code

```
import wx

class harry(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent,id):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,parent,id,'Frame aka Window', size=(300,200))
        panel=wx.Panel(self)

        box = wx.TestEntryDialog(None ,"Whats ur Name ?" ,"Title","default text")
        if box.showModal()==wx.Id_OK:
            answer=box.getValue()

if __name__=='__main__':
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = harry(parent=None,id=-1)
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

The error i get is

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:\pybuck\pytuts9.py", line 14, in <module>
 frame = harry(parent=None,id=-1)
 File "C:\pybuck\pytuts9.py", line 8, in __init__
 box = wx.TestEntryDialog(None ,"Whats ur Name ?" ,"Title","default text")
 AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'TestEntryDialog'
```

My Motive Is to input the user to write its input ( like name ) in the window aka frame thats pops up !
Thanks ,
Harry

Comment: my computer is 64 bit but i downloaded 32 bit python ( 2.7) idle by mistake so to cope with that i am using wxpython with 32 bit !

is that the problem bro

Comment: No, the real problem is the one @nepix32 told you.  You are mistaking Test for Text. I neither realize it when reading

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you are searching for `wx.TextEntryDialog` (as far as I know there is no `wx.TestEntryDialog`?

*Edit:* The Name of things in Python is case-sensitive! `AttributeError` is a nice way of python telling you: "Hey dude, what you searching for, does not exist!". You have the following possibilities to search for things which you think are there, but are not.

- [Read the manual for wx.Dialog](http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/Dialog.html#Dialog.ShowModal)
- Use a GUI which supports Python and code completion (e. g. Eclipse + PyDev)
- invoke dir(wx.TextEntryDialog)

All three will tell you to use `ShowModal` instead of `showModal`.

Comment: I Watched this tuts from here --> http://youtu.be/5SJO9dk9uOQ
and wx.TextEntryDialog is working there fine in the tutorial. as far i think that is not the problem . 

though i can't full guarantee as i am new to python

Comment: @Harry you are not using TextEntryDialog but TestEntryDialog. Check your code

Comment: @joaquin thanks buddy for correcting silly mistake 

but the same error still occurs .... something else is the problem dude

Comment: @Harry edit you question with the correct wx method and the current error. Note that after correcting your mispelling you should not have the same error traceback

Comment: @nepix32 ... THANKS IT WORKED ! Your Edit of your post ! cheers